# JqueryMobile doesn't load linked page at all

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get jQueryMobile working using that latest Alpha release (3) and jQuery 1.5 from the CDNs. The code that is rendered is below. Whenever I click on the link from the page, it just sits on the spinner and never loads. But when I click on the link from the source, the page loads. Anyone have any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head>
    ... 
    <link href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'></script> 
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js'></script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div data-role='page'> 
      <div data-role='header'> 
        <h1>Some Text</h1> 
      </div> 
      <div data-role='content'> 
        <ul data-role='listview'> 
          <li><a href="/persons/1">This is a test</a></li> 
        </ul> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
    <div id='footer'>Some text</div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried a full link starting with http:// or removing the first slash to see what happens? 

Also - install firebug and see what firefox is trying to load when you c lick. This should answer your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the view it was looking for was not a mobile view. It was returning a standard view which didn't have the JQM controls loaded onto it.

Comment: I found this article very helpful in tricking the page to load JQM controls: [How to Trick jQueryMobile](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2011/05/24/Re-skin-your-existing-web-app-using-jQuery-Mobile.aspx)